# Thread safe circuit breaker

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I'm trying to implement the circuit breaker pattern as a learning experience (I know that this pattern is implemented in multiple frameworks already).

My naive, simplified and not thread safe implementation looks something like

```
CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = null;
    try {
        //get the current circuit breaker
        if (circuitBreaker.isOpen()) {
             throw new CircuitBreakerOpenException();
        } else {
             //proceed normally
             //or retry if half open
        }
    } catch (CircuitBreakerCallbackExecutionException e) {
        //update or replace the circuit breaker
    }
```

How can I make a thread safe implementation without synchronizing over the guarded call (the circuit breaker object)? Ideally if the fail threshold is set 10 I don't want to allow more than 10 multithreaded calls to go through the guard if the remote system is failing.

So far I have not found any open source framework that seems 100% thread safe. But maybe there is no point in trying to achieve that.

This question is more about thread safety than about circuit breakers.

Comment: just to clarify: I know why this is not thread safe. But what I do not know is how to make it thread safe.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the question or I'm mis-reading, are you saying you never want more than 10 calls active at any time? Otherwise, if 100 calls pass the breaker before the system fails, you'll have 100 active calls still "inside" the code protected by the breaker, where you're saying you want at most 10.

Comment: lets say the the remote system is up and everything is working correctly. but at some point all calls to the remote system are timed out. What I want is to limit those call that get for instance a TimedOutException to not be more then say 10.

Comment: I could achieve this by synchronizing over the circuit breaker but that would drastically decrease the throughput of the system.

Comment: Why I'm asking; your limit of 10 TimeoutExceptions will require throttling _before_ the breaker is invoked, which still means a lock. Since the breaker can only fail calls _at entry_, the 11th call can't pass the breaker until one of the other calls is done or you'll get an 11th TimeoutException() if all 11 active calls time out.

Comment: so you are saying that it is impossible to implement? :)

Comment: The breaker can be made [wait-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Wait-freedom) (using [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) would probably be a good start), but I can't think of any way to combine it with throttling without introducing a single lock/wait.

Comment: then we have come to the same conclusion!

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, the `isOpen` method accesses a shared variable, presumably a `boolean`. All you need is to make that boolean `volatile`. This will ensure that any write to it by the health-checking thread is immediately visible to all resource-acquiring threads.

Comment: you have understood correctly! however I'm doing stuff like              if (condition) do something  => race condition

Comment: I don't see the race condition there. You would have to give more details for that to become obvious. Note that there would be no need for the condition to hold while you are "doing something".